# Using `clearpage` after `figure*` in revtex gives error "Output routine didn't use all of \box255"

Tags: floats, revtex, clearpage

The problem can be replicated (I hope) with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage

Some (or none) text

\end{document}
```

What happens is that the error `Output routine didn't use all of \box255. []` is given, the image does not appear, and some blank pages are inserted instead.

The error doesn't show up changing most of the details in the above MWE. For example, it doesn't happen if:

1. `revtex` is not used, or even if just the `twocolumn` option is not given
2. The package `graphicx` is used instead of `tikz` to provide `\includegraphics`
3. `figure` is used instead of `figure*`.

The problem still appears if:

1. Instead of `\clearpage` I use `\FloatBarrier`,
2. The `\clearpage` command is before instead of after the `figure*`,
3. `revtex4` is used instead of `revtex4-1`.

However, I need all of these elements in my actual document.
The case in which I experience the above is a long (around 10 pages) paper, written in `revtex4-1`, in which I need to flush a long series of space-consuming wide-text figures before the bibliography. I however find myself completely unable to do so due to the above problem.
I need the `tikz` package because the figures are partly built via `tikz` commands.
I need the figures to be printed before the bibliography because if I don't explicitly impose so they end up scattered in the middle of various pieces of bibliography.

I tried a wide variety of combinations of solutions, but none worked.
The best workaround I found was to have all the images printed *after* the bibliography, but that also is not acceptable because I also need to have an appendix after the bibliography, and I cannot have the images printed after also all the appendices, nor I want them scattered around the text of the appendices.
Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

## EDIT

David Carlisle's fix works on the above MWE. When used on a case with two figures, each composed of a pair of minipages, the dimensions of the second one are somehow changed with the fix.
See the following new MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}

\clearpage

Some (or none) text

\end{document}
```

which results after using the fix suggested in
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea, but...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\onecolumngrid@push\makeatother
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage
\makeatletter\onecolumngrid@pop\makeatother


Some (or none) text

\end{document}
```

---

You need to account for `\columnwidth` changing meaning when you locally switch to one column (actually `\columnwidth` was probably wrong anyway as you were not separating your minipages by `columnsep`).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\onecolumngrid@push\makeatother
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}

\clearpage
\makeatletter\onecolumngrid@pop\makeatother

Some (or none) text

\end{document}
```

Comment: this solves the problem in the posted MWE. Unfortunately, it doesn't in my actual case, and in the MWE as soon as a second figure is added. See edited MWE. By the way, I like to try (and always fail) to understand what's going under the hood, but I cannot find where `\onecolumngrid@push` is defined. I don't find it in `source2e` nor in the code for `revtex` (where is used but not defined it seems)

Comment: actually, on second try it actually does work in the sense that the error disappears (I was putting `\clearpage` outside of the two commands). However, now my figures' sizes were completely changed. I'll try to come out with a MWE replicating this

Comment: see the updated example. The workaround doesn't work if there are two `figure*` each composed of a pair of `minipage`s... LaTeX *really* puzzles me sometimes

Comment: it's from  ltxgrid.sty in the revtex directory, I just guessed by the name of the command and the fact that revtex uses it to wrap longtable that it might help here.I'll ty your new example.... @glS

Comment: @glS see update

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. It really looks like magic though. Do you have any idea as to why this happens? Some inconsistency in the way some things are defined in `revtex` and `tikz`? Is it to be considered a bug?

Comment: @glS tikz is not involved at all is it?  the revtex output routine clearly has some "features" with spanning floats at a `\clearpage` so this just does `\onecolumn` ...floats \clearpage \twocolumn`  so the floats are in single column mode, but for some reason `revtex` does not expose `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` as document commands but has these internal versions hidden away that seem to work here.

Comment: But if I replace tikz with graphicx that error disappears. You don't see this?

Comment: @glS ah i saw now you said that, `\includegraphics` is the same, tikz probably adds a special at the start of a page, I could possibly trace but....